# I don’t want to watch this programme. You can turn it off. (about "it")

Tags: pronouns

I have the following in my grammar book:

> I don’t want to watch this programme. You can turn **it** off.

Is it possible "it" is a TV, not a programme?
So, if we have in a previous sentence an object, in the next sentence that "it" can be only that object or "it" can be something new that hasn't mentioned before, but it can be implied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any other information, a pronoun is usually understood to refer to the most recently mentioned nominal phrase that makes sense.<sup>1</sup> However, a pronoun can refer to something that is not mentioned as long as the referent is clear. For example:

> A: (pointing to a television) Do you want to keep watching?
> B: No, turn **it** off.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are exceptions, of course, such as for dummy pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule that says you can only use a pronoun after the thing has already been mentioned, if that's what you're asking. A pronoun can be used anywhere that it's clear what it refers to. Often this is when the thing is mentioned before, but sometimes it's obvious from the context.

In the context where we're watching TV together and you're about to leave and give me the remote control, I could say:

> *I'm going to bed. You can turn it off*

It would be 100% clear I'm talking about the TV, not about my bed.